# -fx-font-weight: bold not working for Javafx 17

Tags: css, scenebuilder, gluon, javafx-17

Recently, We shift our project Javafx8 to Javafx17. All css properties seems to be working fine but `-fx-font-weight: bold` not working. We are stuck on this since last two days. We have tried every possible solution But, it is not working.

```
"-fx-font-weight: bold;"
```

we also tried with numeric values and by code and external css :

```
"-fx-font-weight: 700;" i.e. label.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 10));
```

Seems like there is some change but we couldn't find at documentation.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Shame no-one has responded to you. For me `-fx-font: 'Arial';-fx-font-weight: bold;` doesn't work at all with the `Text` element but works fine with `text.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 36));`